# Pandas: skip_footer and iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I need to iterate through large files and I specify the data type:

```
data = pd.read_table(file, chunksize=50000, dtype=dtype)
for df in data:
    ...
```

Recently, there was a format change. The last row now contains the word `END`. This leads of course to an error as I specify the data type:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'END'
```

Is there a possibility to exluce the last line while iterating over the file? I tried:

```
data = pd.read_table(file, chunksize=50000, skipfooter=1, convertes=dtype, engine='python')
for df in data:
    ...
```

but it tells me that `skip_footer` does not support iteration:

```
ValueError: skip_footer not supported for iteration
```

An obvious solution is to read everything as string, check for the last line, remove it and only afterwards set the data type. Is there a more elegant and faster alternative?

---

Here is a minimal working example with the various versions from the comments:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

string = "a,b\n0,'x'\n1,'y'\n2,'z'\n'END','END'"

# Test that it works
pd.read_csv(StringIO(string))
#       a      b
#0      0    'x'
#1      1    'y'
#2      2    'z'
#3  'END'  'END'

# Now with data types and iteration

# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'END'"
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), dtype={'a': np.int, 'b': np.str}, chunksize=2)
for df in data: 
    print(df)

# Same error message with error_bad_lines=False
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), dtype={'a': np.int, 'b': np.str}, chunksize=2, error_bad_lines=False)
for df in data: 
    print(df)

# Trying to skip the footer: 
# ValueError: skip_footer not supported for iteration
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), converters={'a': np.int, 'b': np.str}, chunksize=2, skipfooter=1, engine='python')
for df in data: 
    print(df)

# In this mwe, comment='E' gives a different error than in my real data, but still
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'"
data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(string), dtype={'a': np.int, 'b': np.str}, chunksize=2, comment='E')
for df in data:
    print(df)
```

Comment: try passing `error_bad_lines=False` this should skip the last line

Comment: @BayerSe, Use the comment argument in `read_csv`, like `comment='E'`. This would remove the string, "END" from the series containing integers.

Comment: @EdChum same error mesage, nothing changes

Comment: Sorry did you try without `skipfooter=1` and including `error_bad_lines=False`?

Comment: I'm confused here, because this should work? In your code, you have `skipfooter=1` and you specify `engine='python'`, which should work according to [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). But in your error code, you have `skip_footer`, which will not be recognized as a valid command.

Comment: @NickilMaveli `comment='E'` yields another error:  `ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 4`

Comment: @EdChum I tried without `skipfooter=1` and with `error_bad_lines=False`.

Comment: actually that only works with c engine, can you also remove the `engine='python'` param

Comment: @BayerSe, Seems you've got missing values in column 4 which get computed as `NaN`(float type). Add `dtype=np.float64` to read them as floats and later you can decide how you would like to compute these missing values and finally cast them altogether as `int` via `df.astype(int)`.

Comment: @EdChum I added a minimal working example.

Comment: @NickilMaveli  I added a minimal working example.